# Finding CSS value in pixels regardless of browser zoom

Tags: jquery, css, zooming

I have made a small JS fiddle to demonstrate my problem. When you zoom in and out of the page with your browser, the `max-width` value that is being logged to the console changes, but in the CSS it is *always* going to be 500px. How can I find the original CSS value, for instance `max-width`, regardless of if you're zoomed in or not?

http://jsfiddle.net/85uWH/

Comment: I've just tried your JSFiddle on IE8 and Firefox 10 and they both consistenly show 500px, which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Safari - Chrome does it too.

Comment: Ok sorry but i dont have that one install on my pc :(

Comment: If you put the property you want in a `style` attribute in the element (in this example `<div style="max-width:500px">`) you can retrieve its value with `(element).style.maxWidth`, and that will consistently be `500px`. Not sure if this will help though.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really want to do inline styles. Last resort! But thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I had to use (this JavaScript plugin)[https://github.com/yonran/detect-zoom/] which provides the zoom level. In order to calculate the original CSS value, I just multiplied by the zoom level:

```
parseFloat($('div').css('max-width')) * zoomLevel
```

For instance, if the browser was zoomed in at the level of 2:

```
250 * 2
```

Which of course would return the original pixel value of 500px.